# add screenshot of MKMapview to AlertView is not working

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, xcode5.0.1

I have the following code to take a screenshot of the mapview and view this screenshot in the alert view.
I can't find where the problem is!

here is the alertview code :

```
UIAlertView *alertBox=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"image Info." message:@"here is your image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40)];
[imageView setImage:[self renderToImage]];

[alertBox addSubview:imageView];
[alertBox show];
```

and this is the method's code :

```
 - (UIImage*) renderToImage{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mapMKMapView.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
[mapMKMapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return viewImage;
 }
```

any help will be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would break the problem into 2 parts.  Part 1: does renderToImage work correctly.  Check that this function returns a correct UIImage.  Part 2: can you put a different UIImage into the alert box.  Once you find out where the break point is you have found your bug

Comment: I guess it is the problem with alertview. `addSubView` is deprecated in iOS 7 :/

Answer (score 1):

Adding some controls to `UIAlertView` was ***deprecated*** in iOS7 using `addSubview` method. So you need to test your app in two different targets (1. iOS7 and 2. < iOS7) to check whether problem is in code or because of iOS versions.

Comment: you are right my friend, thats what I found in apple developer site.